# How to avoid special character from RETS using phrets?

Tags: rets, phrets

Is there any mechanism to avoid junk/special character from RETS server using DMQL queries and phrets?

for eg: Avoid enclosed double quotes ("value") from the data. Also avoiding character combination like ("value/"), this is causing lots of issues too.

I can escape once downloaded using php script. But then question is, any direct method that handle such escape from RETS end itself?

Thanks

Comment: Can you explain why double quotes are problematic?  Can you provide an actual example of data that gives you problems?   You can control character encoding handling in RETS, but your problem doesn't sound like an encoding issue.

Comment: problem is, that I need to create a JSON string and that also need to inside the CSV. so either CSV or JSON breaks.

Comment: If the quotes are supposed to be there, then you should escape them in your CSV or JSON.  I think in CSV you can replace all `"` with `""` and in JSON you replace all `"` with `\"`.

Answer (score 0):

Theres nothing I can find in the specification that escapes or ignores characters for you.   This feature is beyond the scope of RETS.

The real question being asked here is how to encode JSON in CSV format.

Here is the string you want to encode

`"one","two"`

say its stored in the `start` variable

Let encode it as a JSON object:

`jsonString = '{"data":"' + start.Replace('"','\\"') + '"}';`

`-> {"data":"\"one\",\"two\""}`

Test it at [jsonlint.com](http://jsonlint.com) and observe its valid JSON

So if you needed to store this in a CSV file, then you have to encode it again.

`string csvJsonString = '"' + jsonString.Replace('"','""') + '"';`

`-> "{""data"":""\""one\"",\""two\""""}"`

string validCsv = csvJsonString + "," + csvJsonString

`-> "{""data"":""\""one\"",\""two\""""}","{""data"":""\""one\"",\""two\""""}"`

Test this at [csvlint.io](http://csvlint.io) and see that its valid CSV.

At this point the string validCsv is not valid JSON any more of course, it must be parsed by a CSV reader back into JSON.

Comment: The requirement is, one of the CSV column needs JSON string. So like your comment on my question, if am escaping " with "" it will clear CSV issue only not JSON string inside csv. For JSON fix again like you said " with \" will break csv (eg: {"SortAs": "SGML", "Terms": ""one","two","three"","sqft": "20'6""} ). These scenarios making break

Comment: in the above example, if am escaping it will be like,
{"SortAs": "SGML", "Terms": "\"one\",\"two\",\"three\"","sqft": "20'6\""}
combination of \", will break CSV

Comment: Check the answer for details.  You cant expect the resulting string to be compatible in JSON and CSV at the same time.  The data needs to be encoded in JSON first, then that JSON must be encoded into CSV.  When the file is read, a CSV reader unpackages everything then you can access the valid JSON again.